# Как выполнить несколько команд в XFCE-терминале, вызванном посредством subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь вызвать терминал XFCE в системе Xubuntu 18 и выполнить две команды. Вариант

```
subprocess.call("xfce4-terminal --execute 'ssh user@x.x.x.x -p 22;cd /home/web'", shell=True)
```

выдает ошибку "не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок эssh user@x.x.x.x -p 22;cd /home/web'(нет такого файла или каталога) "?
Пробовал с Pyautogui - глючит: то работает, то нет.

Comment: Из shell-а просто: `xfce4-terminal -e "sh -c 'ls; id; who; sleep 5'"` Главное не забыть в конце команду, которая отсрочит завершение. / Видимо в python надо сформировать аналогичную строку текста и выполнить ее

Comment: Зачем вообще отдельный терминал?

Answer (score 0):

Вот это должно сработать:

```py
subprocess.call("xfce4-terminal --execute 'команда1;команда2'", shell=True)
```

Comment: а что изменено?)

Comment: Не работает, потому что приложение посылает вторую команду не дожидаясь ответа после ввода первой. У меня первая команда - SSH(подключиться к серверу), а вторая - cd (перейти в папку). И получается, что еще не подключившись 'ssh' вводит 'cd' и выдает ошибку(не найден каталог!). Как сделать последовательно?

Comment: @ArturHan, напишите **какие конкретно** команды вы хотите выполнить и где (что на локальном, а что уже на удаленном компьютере). Тогда, imho,  вам смогут реально помочь (иначе придется читать вам много лекций, а желающих квалифицированно сделать это тут скорее всего не окажется)

Comment: исправил вопрос. Можете посмотреть?

Comment: @ArturHan, толком не понял. Вы хотите сделать `cd` **после окончания** `ssh`? (откровенно говоря, это не имеет смысла) / Или эта `cd` должна быть первой командой **внутри** `ssh`?

Comment: Первой командой внутри ssh, т.е. перейти в папку уже на сервере

Comment: @ArturHan, и это должен быть  интерактивный `ssh`, т.е. далее пользователь вводит шелловские команды?

Comment: Например, ls, mcedit, scp и др. И окно терминала остаётся открытым

Comment: @ArturHan, например, в языке Си для этого вам надо создать вот такую строку: ` char cmd[] = "xfce4-terminal -e \"ssh avp@192.168.0.105 sh -c 'pwd; cd /tmp/; bash -i'\"";` и выполнить ее через вызов `system(cmd);` / Очевидно, что-то аналогичное надо делать и в питоне. Однако, мне не удалось 1) избавиться от команды перед `cd /tmp` на сервере; 2) запустить полноценно bash  (его диагностика `bash: cannot set terminal process group (9937): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell`) / Похоже на эту тему --- ssh/bash вам нужно будет задавать дополнительные вопросы

Comment: @ArturHan, проблема полноценного bash решается добавлением ключа `-t` в `ssh`, т.е. вам надо исполнить строчку: `xfce4-terminal -e "ssh -t user@host sh -c 'cd; cd /home/web; bash -i'"` (без первого `cd` (который ничего на экран не выводит) почему-то переход по второму `cd` не у меня работает). Теперь интерактивные программы (vi и т.п.) работают нормально